# Animation not showing up and an animation is duplicating as it moves across the screen

Tags: javascript

I am an inexperienced beginner in JavaScript and am creating a simple game/animation. One of my animations on screen is duplicating as it moves across. Also one of my animations is not showing up at all. I do not know why this is happening. Sorry if this is because of a dumb mistake.

```
// Background \\
  fill ("lightgrey");
  rect(0,0,400,400);
// Sprites/Var \\
  var blueBike = createSprite(50,350,10,10);
  blueBike.setAnimation("bike");
  var redBike = createSprite(100,350,10,10);
  redBike = createSprite("bikeTwo");
// Character \\
function draw() {
  blueBike.y = blueBike.y - randomNumber(1,100);
  redBike.y = redBike.y - randomNumber(1,10);
  drawSprites();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using P5.play library? You should add this info to your question, also the complete code to see how the sprites are loaded etc. Anyway, if so you need to redraw the background in the draw function.

```
function draw() {
  background('lightgrey');
...
  drawSprites();
}
```

And I guess that the sprite animation that does not show up is not loaded correctly. Either it is missing, or you are using a wrong path/filename/filetype.